# Build form base on options in Symfony2

Tags: forms, symfony

I don't know how to dynamically create form based on an **options array**. The builder will use that array to create fields and their options. For example, in my option array has `{'name' => array{'type' => 'string', 'options' => {'required'}}`, the form will be

```
public function buildForm($builder){
    // I think options will be parse here....

    $builder->add('name', 'string', array('required'=>true));
}
```

Does anyone know of a good way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a form specialist, buy you should make a form factory.
Reading this : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html should help